# What does 0##*/ do in ZSH?

Tags: zsh

I understand it is a pattern and it causes some searching to happen:

```
zsh: no matches found: 0##*/
```

However, I have no idea what it is searching against or what command line tool is actually fielding the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error comes from zsh itself doing filename expansion (AKA globbing).  This is covered in the **filename generation** section of the *zshexpn* man page.

If you have the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option set (covered in the *zshoptions* man page) the `##` token behaves like a `+` would in an extended regular expression, matching 1 or more occurrences of the preceding item (`0` in your example). The following `*` would match any sequence of characters (including nothing). The `/` at the end would limit the matches to directories. So the entire pattern would match any directory in your current directory where the name begins with `0`.  Although there isn't really any reason to use the `##` portion; it wouldn't affect the results and makes the pattern more confusing and non-portable to other shells.

If that option isn't set the `##` characters would be taken literally. The `*` and `/` characters would be treated the same as I described in the preceding paragraph.  The entire pattern would match any directory in your current directory where the name begins with `0##`.